# Swift: Set UIBarButtonItem as source for popover WITHOUT tap?

Tags: swift, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I want to show a popover on iPad as soon as my view loads having as source a button on the top right corner.
The popover displays properly on button tap, but I'm having trouble finding a way to display it without the button tap, when the page first loads. Is this possible?

This is what I have:

```
func displayOptions(sourceButton: UIBarButtonItem)
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    if let popoverController = actionSheet.popoverPresentationController {
        var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)              
        popoverController.barButtonItem = sourceButton              
        popoverController.sourceRect = rect 
        popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .up
    }
    viewController.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This code works properly on button tap, but the app crashes if I try to call this function from viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear:

> You must provide location information for this popover through the alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate

Code example:

- viewDidLoad

  ```
  let buttonCustom = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Custom", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.customBarButtonAction))
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = buttonCustom
  displayOptions()
  ```
- displayOptions

  ```
  func displayOptions() {
      let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
      if let popoverController = actionSheet.popoverPresentationController {
          let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
          popoverController.sourceRect = rect
          popoverController.sourceView = self.view
          popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .up
          popoverController.delegate = self
      }
      self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  ```
- using UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate

  ```
  func prepareForPopoverPresentation(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
      popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to provide the `sourceView`.
2. `UIAlertController` must have a `title`, a `message` or an action to display.

   ```
   // Create a bar button item in ViewDidLoad.
   let button1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "imagename"), style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector("action"))
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = button1


   // Call in ViewDidLoad
   displayOptions(sourceButton: button1)

   func displayOptions(sourceButton: UIBarButtonItem) {
       let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
       if let popoverController = actionSheet.popoverPresentationController {
         let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
         popoverController.barButtonItem = sourceButton
         popoverController.sourceRect = rect
         popoverController.sourceView = self.view
         popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .up
       }
       self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the app crashes with the same error message after adding this line.

Comment: are you getting the same error or different error? where are you calling displayOptions function. Update the question with full code.

Comment: Like I said, the error is exactly the same as before. I'm trying to call this function from viewDidLoad, but tried from viewDidAppear too with same result.

Comment: check my updated answer. If error persist, show me source button which is UIBarButtonItem code.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Your answer works, like my original code, for when there is a button tap, but still crashes when I call the function from viewDidLoad.

Comment: I got to see the result if I call via viewDidLoad with my above answer.